# How-to: Optimize Symfony's forms' performance?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have a form that is the bottleneck of my ajax-request.

```
    $order = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:Order')
        ->find($id);
    $order = $order ? $order : new Order();

    $form = $this->createForm(new OrderType(), $order);

    $formView = $form->createView();

    return $this->render(
        'AcmeMyBundle:Ajax:order_edit.html.twig',
        array(
            'form' => $formView,
        )
    );
```

For more cleaner code I deleted `stopwatch` statements.

My **OrderType** has next fields:

```
    $builder
        ->add('status') // enum (string)
        ->add('paid_status') // enum (string)
        ->add('purchases_price') // int
        ->add('discount_price') // int
        ->add('delivery_price') // int
        ->add('delivery_real_price', null, array('required' => false)) // int
        ->add('buyer_name') // string
        ->add('buyer_phone') // string
        ->add('buyer_email') // string
        ->add('buyer_address') // string
        ->add('comment') // string
        ->add('manager_comment') // string
        ->add('delivery_type') // enum (string)
        ->add('delivery_track_id') // string
        ->add('payment_method') // enum (string)
        ->add('payment_id') // string
        ->add('reward') // int
        ->add('reward_status') // enum (string)
        ->add('container') // string
        ->add('partner') // Entity: User
        ->add('website', 'website') // Entity: Website
        ->add('products', 'collection', array( // Entity: Purchase
            'type' => 'purchase',
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'property_path' => 'purchases',
            'error_bubbling' => false,
        ));
```

**Purchase type**:

```
    $builder
        ->add('amount')
        ->add('price')
        ->add('code', 'variant', array(
            'property_path' => 'variantEntity',
            'data_class' => '\Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Simpla\Variant'
        ))
    ;
```

Also **Purchase type** has a listener that is not significant here. It is represented in Symfony profiler below as `variant_retrieve`, `purchase_form_creating`. You can see that it takes about 200ms.

Here I put the result of profilers:
[image: SymfonyProfiler]
[image: BlackFire Profiler]
[image: BlackFire Profiler]

As you can see: `$this->createForm(...)` takes 1011ms, `$form->createView();` takes 2876ms and form rendering in twig is also very slow: 4335ms. As stated by blackfire profiler all the deal in `ObjectHydrator::gatherRowData()` and `UnitOfWork::createEntity()`.

Method `createEntity()` called 2223 times because there is some field that mapped with `Variant` entity and has form type `Entity`. But as you can see from above code there is no `entity` types for variant. My `VariantType` is simple extended `text` form type that has `modelTransformer`. To not mess up everything you can see code for similar Type class at [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#using-transformers-in-a-custom-field-type).

I found with XDebug that `buildView` for `VariantType` has been called in `Purchase`'s `buildView` with `text` form type. But after that from somewhere `buildView` for `VariantType` was called again and in this case it has `entity` form type. How can it be possible? I tried to define empty array in  `choices` and `preferred_choices` on every my form type but it didn't change anything. What I need to do to prevent `EntityChoiceList` to be loaded for my form?

Comment: As far as I know, at least with templating, it may be due to the absence of twig caching with dev environment.

Comment: It is a good idea to profile the script without twig and count how many times `createEntity()` called in this case. I'll check it.

Comment: Without Twig it also call `getEntity` and so `createEntity` exactly 2223 times.

Comment: How many `Product` and `Variant` do you have ?

Comment: In this particular query 1 Product and 1 Variant.

Comment: Could you try testing it without having the products collection in the form.  If its much faster than you know this collection is responsible.  Can you post your Purchase and Order entities?  Does the Purchase entity have associations and cascade persists with other entities?  I think there is a manytomany join lurking somewhere.

Comment: Are you loading the form via AJAX? If so, why not have the form render as part of the page, but populate the fields via AJAX just returning JSON. It might be lighter (ie not in the MB range) and require less processing.

Comment: @George as stated in my question I know that the `products` collection is responsible. And `Purchase` and `Order` entities have almost every field from appropriate form types and some extra fields that are populated in some listeners. And there is no many-to-many relations.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for your advice. I know other solutions. The question is about form processing in Symfony. Not about alternatives to the forms.
And yes we will refactor this part of project to use AJAX but later.

Answer (score 2):

The described behavior looks as the work of the guesser. I have the feeling that there is need to show an some additional code (listeners, `VariantType`, `WebsiteType`, `PartnerType`).

Let's assume a some class has association `variant` to `Variant` and `FormType` for this class has code `->add('variant')` without explicit specifying type (as I see there is a lot of places where the type is not specified). Then `DoctrineOrmTypeGuesser` comes in the game.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/DoctrineOrmTypeGuesser.php#L46

This code assign the `entity` type (!) to this child. The `EntityRepository::findAll()` is called and all variants from DB are hydrated.

As for another form optimization ways:

- Try to specify type in all possible cases to prevent a type guessing;
- Use SELECT with JOINs to get an order as new sub-requests to DB are sent to set an underlying data for an every form maps relation;
- Preserve keys for collection elements on a submission as a removing of a single element without a keys preserving will trigger unnecessary updates.

Comment: As you can see from my code I have already specified type for variant form. It has `text` type with transform listener. Website and Partner entities do not have overhead.

Comment: How the generated html looks like? In what place does `entity` code (radiobuttons, checkboxes or selectbox) appear?

Comment: I override default theme to generate hidden input instead of standard text input for variant choice type. For Webiste and Partners I generate own select list with overridden form theme.

Comment: I think it will be useful to enable default theme with most generic code `{{ form(form) }}` to see in which position vriant's `entity` will appear.

Comment: It is not necessary. I can see that `code` field in `variantType` has entity type from symfony debug toolbar.

Comment: And I checked with debugger that this TypeGuesser doesn't process `code` field. It just process fields that are declared in the entity explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with the entity type, I needed to list cities, there were like mire then 4000, what I did basically is to inject the choices into the form. In your controller you ask the Variants from the database, in a repository call, hydrate them as array, and you select only the id and the name, or title, and then you pass into the form, as options value. With this the database part will be much quicker.

Comment: I don't need to fetch anything. I have an order, order has one purchase, that purchase has one product, that product has one variant. I don't need any entity's choice lists.

Comment: It is not about queries. 9 queries to DB. I just updated my question to be more clear.