# Big form collections with Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

I'm having some trouble with a big form in Symfony2. Let me explain the situation:

A client of me offers **one day courses** and I'm building an application  where participants can sign up for a particular course. The process is simple: a participant logs in, selects a course, selects a date and signs up.

This involves multiple entities:

1. **Course**, ~20 required properties, OneToMany with **CourseDate**
2. **CourseDate**, ~1 required property, OneToMany with **CoureDateParticipant**
3. **CourseDateParticipant**, ~20 properties, ManyToOne with **Participant**

The properties of **CourseDateParticipant** are almost the same als **Course**, most of them are only used to override a property of **Course** in some cases. So most of the times the majority of the **CourseDateParticipants** properties will be *null*.

In the backend I'm having one form where the admin can add and edit a whole course at once. The form is similar to the entities I.e. **CourseType** with a collection of **CourseDateType** with a collection of **CourseDateParticipantType**.

Everything is working fine, except with the big courses. A **Course** can contain up to *50* **CourseDate**, a **CourseDate** can contain up to *1000* **CourseDateParticipant**. Every property has its own field, so with these numbers a form will contain 50*1000*20 = 1.000.000 fields. But, most of these fields will be *null*.

I already did some Jquery magic to make the UI usable. And when adding a **Course** only the filled fields will be submitted. When editing only the changed fields get submitted.

But the controller is choking when calling $form->createView() with such big numbers to be prefilled (when editing). Some solutions I'm thinking of:

- Tell the client to split such big **Course** in little ones. (not my favorite)
- Don't render the **CourseDateParticpant** on initialization, but somehow afterwards if the admin clicks a button. Can be a button to render all, but also a button for each **CourseDateParticipant**.
- Remove many properties from **CourseDateParticipant** and save the exceptions somewhere else.

Do you people have some other/better suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a known problem, check-out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778025/how-to-optimize-symfonys-forms-performance for example.

Comment: Any time you are dealing with 50,000 items you will have problems.  Instead of designing for the worse case why not try an intermediate approach.  For a given course, show the first 10 CourseDates by default.  Give the user next/prev/search buttons.  Do the same for CourseParticipant.